# How to run debug Django app in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

`launch.json`

```
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "DjangoDebugging"
            ]
```

In the browser `http://localhost:8000/login` I have a login page allow user input username and password to login. I put a break points in the code of `def login` in views.py and run debug but the execution is not stopped on the line with break points. Now I want to allow user input user name and password then they click on button and it will jump to break points `def login` in views.py. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use visual studio code to debug django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937544/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-to-debug-django)

Comment: I'm so sorry but I have already followed your link but it can't run. So can you help me? Please @WayneJohnston

Answer (score 7):

Here are instructions for Visual Studio Code version 1.14.2. Older versions may work a bit different.

- Open your project folder in VS Code
- Click Debug icon (or press Ctrl + Shift + D)
- From the drop-down list at the top of the debug pane, select Django
- Click the Start Debugging button (or press F5)

VS Code will open manage.py and start execution. There should be a debugger tool pallet at the top of the IDE with buttons to step, continue, etc. Breakpoints are set by clicking in the code window to the left of the line number.
[image: Django Debugging]

I have these VS Code extensions installed (in case it matters).

- MagicPython 1.0.11
- Python 0.6.9
- Python for VS Code 0.2.3

Comment: Hi @WayneJohnston, thank for your support! I have already followed your guide and the execution stopped on the line with break points of header function but I want to run debug next step to watch the variables value inside of the function how can I do that? If I press F10 it will stop the bebugging. Please check my [screen image](https://ibb.co/jhQnX5). Thank you!

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think you want to press F11 (Step Into) at this point. Step Into will - in effect - take smaller steps as it executes every line. Sometimes this is too much detail but when the debugger doesn't stop at the right place I find it can help. Also, put a breakpoint on the line where you want to see a variable. Again this can be too much detail at times, but if you are having trouble reaching a certain line, force the execution to stop there.