# How to use visual studio code to debug django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I'm new at **django** development and come from desktop/mobile app development with **Xcode** and related IDE.

I have to use Django and I was wondering if there was an efficient way to debug it using **Visual Studio Code** (or **Atom**).

Any help related to Django IDE would be helpful too.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For VSCode (full disclosure, I'm one of the VSCode developers) try installing the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) to get started.

[This documentation covers debugging Django](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Debugging-Django). There should be a included debug configuration or you can add your own to the [`launch.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations):

```
{
    "name": "Django",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "pythonPath": "${config.python.pythonPath}",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
    "args": [
        "runserver",
        "--no-color",
        "--noreload"
    ],
    "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput",
        "DjangoDebugging"
    ]
}
```

The Python extension also provide many other features that you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I find that `Debug Console` won't print django logs.  I figure out that it is because VSCode doesn't support colored logs, so I think `--no-color` argument is also needed here.

Comment: I could be doing this wrong, but I get multiple errors from this, starting with VS Code complaining about not recognizing the pair `"type":"python"`; full-disclosure, I **do** have `MagicPython`, `Python`, `Python Extension Pack`, and `Python for VSCode` installed and running.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with auto reloading? It doesn't look like VSCode supports it but it's a pain to manually restart the server whenever I make a change.

I think you could perhaps set an `attach` debugging config to attach to the port of a server running elsewhere. But I haven't been able to get it working

Comment: @dspacejs joining the party pretty late but in case someone still needs this: just remove the `--noreload` argument (specified in `args`).

Comment: I am using similar config to run a python module, this module is basically a flask app. When u put debugger red dot on any line in any controller the code execution does not pause there. Does anyone have any idea about that?

Answer (score 7):

VSCode has an official tutorial explaining this:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django

There are several steps that need to be taken, which I don't all want to write out manually, since there are quite some steps, but I'll try to summarize what needs to be done:

*The text below is basically a partial copy of the above tutorial, I am not claiming I came up with this myself.*

**1. Make sure to check out the prerequisites** (use VS Code Python extension, install Python on local machine) [link to docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_prerequisites)

**2. Use Python virtual environment** [link to docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_create-a-project-environment-for-the-django-tutorial)

Besides using a Python virtual environment, you also need to select the Python executable inside this virtual environment as the interpreter in VS Code. This can be done like so:

> In VS Code, open the Command Palette (View > Command Palette or (Ctrl+Shift+P)). Then select the Python: Select Interpreter

Then you select the Python executable inside your virtual environment, which you can recognize by it's path.

**3. Create debugger lauch profile**

[as described here, in the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_create-a-debugger-launch-profile)

upper left of the VS Code window)

**4. Now you can start debugging**

[this part of the documentation will give you an introduction on how to do that](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_explore-the-debugger)

Comment: followed the exact steps of that tutorial, but I don't get breakpoints working. Breakpoints in manage.py are hit, but any breakpointrs in my views are just ignored. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Only **experimental** configuration works for me.

```
{
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "pythonExperimental",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
},
```

Standard config causes `Unverified breakpoint` issue.

Comment: Unlike the default option `"type": "python"`, this gives me an error: `The debug type is not recognized. Make sure that you have a corresponding debug extension installed and that it is enabled`. Could you clarify if this requires an extension, and which is it? I have the default Python and Django development extensions installed already.

Answer (score 2):

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Django: makemigrations",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "makemigrations"
            ],
            "django": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Django: migrate",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "migrate"
            ],
            "django": true
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me until I had disabled auto reload (`--noreload` as an argument is crucial, not really sure why it causes problem with debugging)

Comment: `--noreload` still doesn't work for me unfortunately.