# VSCode debugger in Django only stopping when writing out "breakpoint()" on functional views

Tags: python, django, debugging, pipenv

For some reason my debugger was no longer stopping at breakpoints.

I read that this could be caused by some bug in Python version 3.9 > so I've downgraded to using Python 3.8.0 in my environment, but still no luck.

However, the debugger was stopping at the first time when setting up the server, but not when the program was up and running and I was accessing URLs trough the browser.

The only way I had VSCode to stop at the breakpoints was to actually write out "breakpoint()" on a view, and this **only** worked for a functional view.

**I'm using:**

- Django version 3.2.4
- Python 3.8.0 (also tried with Python 3.9.6)
- Pipenv for virtual environment version 2021.5.29

**MY launch.JSON: **
Got this from: [How to use visual studio code to debug django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937544/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-to-debug-django)

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/jobs/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--no-color",
            "--noreload"
        ],
        "django": true,
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput",
            "DjangoDebugging"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I've also tried adding '"justMyCode": true' to my launch.JSON with no change in behavior.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of the code that's not stopping? The view itself, where you set the breakpoint and all the rest of the django related code to wire it all up

Comment: I've added a short example, nothing special, so I don't believe that's where the problem is

Comment: It makes it easier to set the project without trying to remember django specifics. I used `django-admin startproject mysite` to set up a project, added an app and then added the views/urls there. When using pycharm/vsc to run the project in debug mode it stops in the view (and only when i trigger it, not on launch) EDIT- its expected to break on the urls.py file on start (since its used for bootstrapping the server) but not for the views